# Python Pandas reading time as decimal value

Tags: python, pandas, time

When I am reading a time data from an xlsx file into pandas, it reads as a decimal value.

Example: `9:23:27 AM` is read as `.391284722`

I can fix it by converting it into time using format cell and select time. But I would prefer to use pandas all the way through and not Excel.

When I call the value and convert it into a date time object

```py
df.TIME=pd.to_datetime(df.TIME)
```

It changes to this date `1970-01-01`

Desired time is `9:23:27 AM`

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `pandas.to_datetime` has an implicit inference system where it requires an explicit year/month/day stamp. If it receives none, it will convert the time to a datetime object that begins 1970-01-01. What are you trying to accomplish with the `TIME` column?

Comment: I want pandas to read the time exactly how its coded it should read it as 9.23.27 instead its reading it as .391284722....

Answer (score 3):

Demo:

read that column as string:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype={'col_name':str})

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
          time
0   9:23:27 AM
1  12:59:59 AM

In [52]: df['time2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
          time    time2
0   9:23:27 AM 09:23:27
1  12:59:59 AM 12:59:59

In [54]: df.dtypes
Out[54]:
time              object
time2    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

**UPDATE:** in order to convert a float number (# of seconds) read from Excel
try the following:

Source DF:

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]:
       time
0  0.391285
1  0.391285
2  0.391285
```

Solution:

```
In [94]: df['time2'] = pd.to_timedelta((df['time'] * 86400).round(), unit='s')

In [95]: df
Out[95]:
       time    time2
0  0.391285 09:23:27
1  0.391285 09:23:27
2  0.391285 09:23:27

In [96]: df.dtypes
Out[96]:
time             float64
time2    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Max,
The reading in part is the problem when it reads it reads as a decimal value not as 9:23:27 .....

Comment: @pythonninja, did you use `dtype={'column_name':str}`?

Comment: Yes i did.. it reads as a much longer string 0.3912847222222222

Comment: Thank you Max that updated answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question could use some clarifying for an end-purpose for the time-column. For general purposes though, try using the `format` keyword in `to_datetime`.

```
df.TIME=pd.to_datetime(df.TIME, format='%I:%M%S %p')
```

See this website for formatting: http://strftime.org/

Comment: There is no date in the time column....Only time is involved. When I read time It coverts the time to a decimal value.